# Figure Caption format = hang doesn't work the way I hoped

Tags: floats, lyx, captions

The following is the format I use, KOMA-Script, for some reason after using `\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}` the figure caption in the second row is shift to the right from the first capital. I would like to align to the first capital. What is wrong?

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}
}
\def\refnamechanges{%
 \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}%
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}%
}
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}{\addto\extrasenglish{\refnamechanges}}{\refnamechanges}

\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}


\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \frontmatter
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \mainmatter }

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{cite}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}


\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please edit your question to replace the code snippet by a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your problem. This would help us to reproduce the problem and find an answer. Questions without a MWE from `\documentclass` with `\begin{document}` down to `\end{document}` are always somehow unclear and often result in comments with speculations instead of answers.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `\setcapindent{1em}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
%\setcapindent{1em}% <- remove this line
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbp]
  \caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note: The hanging style of the captions is default for KOMA-Script classes. So there seems to be no need to load package `caption`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I removed \setcapindent{1em} it worked the way it should :)

Comment: Maybe you can accept this answer, if it has solved your problem.